# ¿Cómo hacer conteo en un campo y condicionar el resultado con if y else con mysql y php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

¿Cómo hacer `COUNT` en un campo y condicionar el resultado con `IF` y `ELSE` con `MYSQL` y `PHP`?

```
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) < $Asignacion)
```

Parece que no toma en cuenta la variable `$Asignacion`.

---

ASI OBTENGO EL VALOR DE `$Asignacion`

```
$consulta="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = '$usuario'";

$res=mysqli_query($con,$consulta);

while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    
$Asignacion = ''.$data['asignacion'].'';

}
```

---

MI CONSULTA

$sql="SELECT COUNT(telefono) FROM usuarios WHERE telefono = '$usuario'";

Comment: Sin mayúsculas sostenidas por favor. No es necesario gritar acá. Lo otro: por qué dices que no funciona?